# Profitwell API wrapper build as Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, api

I've created my first gem in Profitwell API wrapper https://github.com/eebasadre20/profitwell. I love to get some feedback, comment, or suggestion on the code structure, method implementations, and so on.

I am more concerned in my code structure like how I structured to handle the module and class, the request-response handling, error handling, and parameters handling.

Here is one of the examples of my resource:

```
module Profitwell
  class Plans
    include Client

    def all
      request(
        "get",
        resource_path("plans")
      )
    end

    def find(plan_id)
      request(
        "get",
        resource_path("plans/#{plan_id}")
      )
    end

    def create(params = {})
      request(
        "post",
        resource_path("plans"),
        options: params
      )
    end

    def update(plan_id, params = {})
      request(
        "put",
        resource_path("plans/#{plan_id}"),
        options: params
      )
    end
  end
end
```

I would be very pleased if you give me some feedback regarding the code structure and implementation - [Profitwell API Wrapper](https://github.com/eebasadre20/profitwell)

Everyone is welcome to share your idea and contribute to this simple project.